# CASE statements - Making the THEN display information from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Good morning All,

I had a question regarding case statements. Let me set up a scenario that I am having a hard time with. Say we have a table with all of our providers licenses. Each provider can have anywhere from one to a number of licenses. I want to create a case statement that says basically WHEN the providers license type equals this, then display the license number from this different column holding the values for their numbers.

Hope this makes sense. I do not want it to display words such as THEN 'Primary Care Physician' , instead would like it to provide the actual license number in the THEN.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is pretty much what the case expression is intended to do.

Comment: Hint: `case when columnName = 'something' then anotherColumnName else....`

Comment: Provide some sample table data and expected output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the CASE syntax as it is described in the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html

```sql
CASE WHEN license_type = 1 THEN license_number_column_a
     WHEN license_type = 2 THEN license_number_column_b
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I Fugere that you are trying to use a code like

```
Case licence_type 
when 1 then licence_number_column_a
when 2 then licence_number_column_b
... 
End
```

This type of Case works exclusively when you are evaluating constants. 
When you are evaluating columns, you need to move the test to "when"

```
Case  
when licence_type = 1 then licence_number_column_a
when licence_type = 2 then licence_number_column_b
... 
End
```